# Is there a theme with no grids?

Tags: theming

Is there a theme I can use which has no grids set up, as I would like to write the mark up from scratch so I can have more control over the breakpoints.

Does such a theme exist?

Comment: Hi, recommendation/list questions aren't a good fit for our Q+A format. Please ask specific, objectively answerable questions that conform to the rules laid out in the [help centre](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help). Thanks

Comment: Amended the question

Comment: Thanks, but the problem with the question is that it's asking for us to list/recommend some themes that match a certain criteria. They're often referred to as ["shopping list questions"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), and aren't allowed anywhere in the network.

Comment: To add to what @Clive said, the "with no grids" requirement is not too restrictive; there would be too much possible answers, which then would change over the time: a theme that was suggested is not actively maintained anymore, new themes that make other themes less preferable are made available. The problem is also that the question doesn't show any research being done, and its answers would be opinion-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many themes which uses the conventional layout methods, one of which I know is the [Bigdaddy](https://drupal.org/project/bigdaddy).

The complete list of such type of themes is available [here](https://drupal.org/node/323993).

Answer (score 0):

To start from something as close to a clean slate as possible you may want to look at making a subtheme of [Mothership](https://drupal.org/project/mothership).